# robot-upstart indigo

Tags: ros, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to use upstart to run my robot application at the startup of the system but I can't configure it.
I currently have my catkin workspace with my tool at /home/robot/workspace and when I run the command:

$rosrun robot_upstart install workspace/src/safe_pilot/launcher/safe_pilot.launch

I have the error:

Unable to located path src/safe_pilot/launcher/safe_pilot.launch in package workspace. Installation aborted.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_upstart/install", line 32, in 
exit(main())
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robot_upstart/install_script.py", line 83, in main
if os.path.isfile(found_path[0]):
IndexError: list index out of range

Does someone has an idea??

tks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202229/robot-upstart-indigo/) by [julien](https://answers.ros.org/users/21518/julien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The argument to `robot_upstart install` is  `pkg/path`.

In your case:

```
$rosrun robot_upstart install safe_pilot/launcher/safe_pilot.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [julien](https://answers.ros.org/users/21518/julien/) on 2015-02-03**:
tks for your answer,

Does it suppose that my package has been installed using catkin_make install ? or can I used the catkin_workspace/devel folder?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-02-03**:
No you don't have to do `catkin_make install`. You also don't have to care about the devel folder. This command should work as it is.

**Comment by [julien](https://answers.ros.org/users/21518/julien/) on 2015-02-16**:
Ok tks it works.
Just a last question: How to remove/suspend the automatic launch... (removing manually the created files??)

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-02-16**:
`robot_upstart` includes an `uninstall` script.

**Comment by [julien](https://answers.ros.org/users/21518/julien/) on 2015-03-03**:
Are you shure ? because in the GIT repository I can't see an uninstall script and the documentation don't speak about it...

I have an other question one of my node is in charge to log data in a file and when I use robot_upstart the file can't be created, does the program is run with a Read-Only opt

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-03-03**:
Oh I see. There was an uninstall script till Mike Purvis ported the install script to python.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-03-16**:
The uninstall script has been restores as of v0.1.2 (not synced to public yet), so either install from the shadow repositories or do a source-install

**Comment by [Ugnius Malukas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30576/ugnius-malukas/) on 2017-09-28**:
Usage of robot_upstart http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/robot_upstart/html/#usage